# Encontrar valor que mais se repete

Tags: python, pandas

Eu estou tentando analisar uns dados de venda de calçados, mas estou com dificuldade em criar uma função para encontrar qual foi a numeração que o cliente mais comprou no ano anterior.

Tenho uma tabela com esses dados:

```
Cód. Cliente    CPF     Nome                            Sexo        Tamanho
5879099     37513584800 LOJA                            MASCULINO   35
5879099     37513584800 LOJA                            MASCULINO   23
5879099     37513584800 LOJA                            MASCULINO   17
5879099     37513584800 LOJA                            MASCULINO   37
5879099     37513584800 LOJA                            MASCULINO   17
3353800     2613618809  DULIO JOSE DE SOUSA DAMICO      MASCULINO   35
3353800     2613618809  DULIO JOSE DE SOUSA DAMICO      MASCULINO   39
3112300     29953652805 ROSANA DA SILVA FAGUNDES        FEMININO    34
6116202     39285701884 ANA CAROLINA DE FARIAS FRANCISCO    FEMININO    31
```

A tabela é bem mais que essa, apenas algumas linhas de exemplo.

Pois bem, o que eu preciso saber é qual é o Tamanho que mais se repete por CPF do cliente.

Qual a numeração que ele mais comprou?

Não encontrei forma de fazer isso, se alguém tiver uma luz.

Obrigado,

Comment: Seria algo como `df['Tamanho'].value_counts().idxmax()`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acredito que algo assim, porém para cada CPF, eu teria que criar uma coluna com CPF unico e uma função para pegar o idmax por cpf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iuri você poderia utilizar *PIVOT TABLE* (tabela dinâmica) no pandas

Seria mais ou menos isso:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("SEU ARQUIVO")
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["CPF","Tamanho"],
               values=["Tamanho"],
               aggfunc=[np.count_nonzero],fill_value=0)
```

Utilizei o *'read_excel'* só como exemplo, no seu caso é só preencher o dataframe com seus dados.

O parâmetro *'index'* monta as colunas da tabela dinâmica, ou seja, as colunas de categoria que você quer utilizar

e no *'aggfunc'*( Função de agregação ) estou utilizando a contagem

Neste [Link](http://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html) tem um conteúdo interessante sobre *Pivot Table* que pode auxiliar mais.